# Chrome stops MPEG-DASH playback after some time

Tags: node.js, video.js, mpeg-dash

I am working on a project which needs to play MPEG-DASH stream playback on top of videojs.
Now the playback of the stream stops playing after 59 seconds. 
See below code and error i am getting

```
<video id="example-video">
    <source src="http://hitsradio.videocdn.scaleengine.net/ondemand/play/mp4:sestore8/hitsradio/ZZ Top - Cheap Sunglasses.mp4/manifest.mpd" type="application/dash+xml">
</video>

<script src="path/to/video.js">
<script src="path/to/videojs-dash.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/dash.all.js"></script>
<script>
    myPlayer = document.getElementById("example-video");
    myPlayer.play()
</script>
```

Now the error i got in browsers

```
[60269][bufferController][video] Waiting for more buffer before starting playback. 
dash.all.js:11 [60271][scheduleController][audio] Stalling Buffer 
dash.all.js:11 [60271][bufferController][audio] Waiting for more buffer before starting playback. 
dash.all.js:11 [60272][playbackController] <video> ratechange:  0
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in video.js. I just tested other web-based players like [dash.js](http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/v2.0.0/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html), [bitmovin's adaptive streaming player](http://www.dash-player.com/demo/manifest-test/) and [Google's Shaka player](http://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/) and all three of them played the stream without problems.

To the best of my knowledge, video.js uses dash.js for MPEG-DASH playback, so either you're using an old dash.js version (I tested the latest v2.0.0) or there is a problem in the video.js DASH plugin. If the later is the problem you should create an issue in their github repository.